# Centering Two Dynamic-Width Divs On The Same Line and

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

Okay I apologize if this is a repeat - but I couldn't find any working answers anywhere.

I want to have two divs (50% width each) side by side...  so a left and a right - inside of a content div `(see photo below)`.

I want them to have min-widths at 300px and once the page gets smaller than 600px (which is when both divs will reach their mins) I want to divs to wrap.. so one on top the other.

I've tried to do that here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzbku/)  but am having problems.

Here is EXACTLY what I want:

[image]

Comment: You should do a quick search for `media query`.

Comment: Also, what good luck you have getting a +5 upvote on your first question.  People who post picture diagrams are my favorite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making things hard for yourself!  This can be done quickly and easily with `inline-block`s.  Have a nice [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzbku/4/).

Lets explain the code:

```
.wrapper
{
    text-align: center;   /* specifies that the inline-blocks (which are treated 
        like text here) will be centered. */

    font-size: 0;  /* Explained later */
    max-width: 1000px;  /* Your desired max-width */
    position: relative;  /* These two lines center your wrapper in the page. */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Now for the inside 50% elements:

```
.left, .right{
    display: inline-block;  /* This will treat these divs like a text element.  
       This will work with the parent's "text-align: center" to center the element. */

    min-width: 300px;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 16px;  /* Explained below */
    vertical-align: text-top;   /* Explained below */
}
```

You might be wondering why `font-size` is included.  It is because with this method comes a little quirk - if a font size is kept at default, the div's will have an annoying gap between them that can not be eliminated with margin.

[image]

However, adding `font-size: 0;` to the parent element eliminates this gap.  It's weird, and you then have to specify the font-size for your children elements, but it's well worth it for the ease of use.

But there's still a problem - the blue element is pushed down, and isn't flush on the top.  This can be remedied with `vertical-align: text-top;`  This will make sure all Div elements are aligned by the tops, so they lay in a more pleasant pattern.  This is just another little quirk to remember when using inline-blocks.  I know it seems like a lot of things to fix just for something this simple, but compared to your other options using `inline-block` is the cleanest and easiest way of going about this.  (Though if you prefer, jshanley offers a very good alternative using float elements)

[image]

Also, because these children are now treated like text, they will automatically reposition themselves when the window gets too small! No media-queries needed. Yay.

Good luck.

Comment: I do think this is a viable approach, with the minor annoyance that you have to go in and realign the text of the inner elements back to `left` if you want regular text in there. But as you said, it's good to have multiple ways presented, especially since the rest of the site's content might make one or the other approach impossible. And +1 for demonstrating the workaround for the font-size quirk

Comment: Obviously this answer DOES WORK.  My question for you, since I'm new to coding, is how do I make the pink content part only as tall as the content it contains?  (Probably a dumb question...) @AlexanderLozada

Comment: @user3558711 - oops, my bad.  Just remove the `height` property from the container, and it will become as tall as the content.  JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mzbku/8/

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using inline-block which causes some sizing quirks, you can use block elements, and float both `.left` and `.right` to the left, giving each a width of `50%`.

Then to make them stack you need to do a little calculating. Since you specified that the wrapper is `80%` of the page width, and the break point for the content is at `600px` (each element 300px) the page's breakpoint would be at `750px` since 80% of 750 is 600.

You can make a media query that will only apply styles when the page width is less than `750px` and set `.left` and `.right` to width 100% to make them stack.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    .left, .right {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

It's very simple to implement, and gives a good result, here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzbku/6/).

Comment: Good alternative to my response.  Either way we run into quirks and extra specifications, but it's always good to have choices.

Comment: @AlexanderLozada Yeah, I suppose when you float the elements you need to worry about clearfix and all that jazz so it really comes down to either personal preference, or which approach plays nicer with the rest of the site's content

Comment: This response seems to work as well, BUT I'm worried that the floats will have problems due to "clearfix and all that jazz" (lol!) because I don't know what that does either...  I really appreciate the response, but because I'm an inexperienced coder I think Alexander's response will help me more.  +1 still.

Comment: @user3558711 yep, personal preference. Glad we found you a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think both @jshanley and @emn178's answers do the trick, but I want to point something out:

The **display: inline-block;** css property doesn't work with **float: right** nor **float: left**, since when you use the float property, it ALWAYS automatically set the display property to block.

Since you're doing this:

```
.right{
   min-width:100px;
   background-color:purple;
   height:100%;
   margin-left:50%;
   display:inline-block;  
}
```

The **display: inline-block;** property is doing nothing.

Comment: This may be better suited as a comment since you aren't particularly answering OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

`left` and `right` could have same layout, so I add a class `block`.
To use `float:left` and `width:50%`, it should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/emn178/mzbku/7/

I add media query, it should be what you want.
But you need to calculate how to set the size.

Comment: This doesn't responsively change the width to 50% since the element is float, rendering the `50%` value superfluous.

Comment: you tried implementing the same 750px media query I gave in my answer 3 mins after I posted it, but you broke your example because now it throws up a scrollbar instead of showing the purple element when the media query is applied. I'll give you -0.25 for trying to pass that off as your own thought, and -0.75 for still not getting the desired result

Comment: I updated because Alexander's comment, not your answer. It's easy to get the number 750. When I was writing the example in jsfiddle, you was posting your answer. It's just in same time. Media query is normal way to do responsive, it's not yours. Everybody could use it.

Comment: Alright, I'll give you the quarter point back. Unfortunately, I still had to round to -1